# How to get dynamic text with one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a comment reply system and when I try to reply to a comment, the first reply works fine.

For any subsequent replies, I can get comment id and article id to submit but I can't get the reply text value.

How can I make this work based on the Razor code below for all replies every time?

```
<h4>Comments</h4>
<hr />
@foreach (var item in Model.Comments.ToList())
{
    <!-- Single Comment -->
    <div class="media mb-4">
        <img style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="@item.User.Photo" alt="@item.User.FullName">
        <div class="media-body" style="width:400px;">
            <h5 class="mt-0">@item.User.UserName</h5>
            <div>
                <p style="word-break:break-all">
                    @item.Paragraph
                    @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]) == item.UserId)
                {
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/Home/DeleteComment/@item.CommentId">
                            Delete
                        </a>

                        <div style="height:10px;"> <a id="post_id_1" name='comment1' class="showReply" href="javascript: void(0)">Reply</a></div>
                    }
                </p>
                <p style="font-size:small"><b>Yorum Tarihi:</b>@String.Format("{0: d MMMM yyyy}", item.Date)</p>
            </div>
            <!--Reply Form-->
            <div id="replymsgbox" style="display: none;">
                <form id="frmComment" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" name="frmComment">
                    <div>
                        <textarea id="replytext" class="" name="comment1[text]"></textarea>
                        <div id="error_text"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="@item.CommentId" class="reply" type="submit" value="Cevapla" name="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>


            @foreach (var reply in Model.ReplyComments.Where(x => x.CommentId == item.CommentId).ToList())
            {
                <div class="media mt-4">
                    <img style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="@item.User.Photo" alt="@item.User.FullName">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">@reply.User.UserName</h5>
                        <p>@reply.Paragraph</p>
                        @if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]) == item.UserId)
                        {
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/Home/DeleteReply/@reply.ReplyCommentId">
                                Sil
                            </a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a.showReply').on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").parent("div").next("div").slideToggle();
    });

    $(".reply").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
        var r_commentid = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
        $.ajax({
             url: '/Home/ReplyComment/',
             data: { replycomment: r_comment, articleid:@Model.ArticleId, commentid: r_commentid },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Cevap gönderildi");
                window.location.reload();

            }
        });

});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l solved my problem with this js code

```
  var r_comment = $(this).closest("form").find(".textreply").val();
```

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements generated with the id of `replytext`. In your on click code, and pretty much everywhere else, you are using class references as selectors which is good. For the replytext though you have:

```
var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
```

You are trying to refer to an element by ID when the ID is duplicated. You will either need to give unique ids to your elements or find a different way as in traverse the DOM manually like you have tried with multiple `.parent()` selectors, or some search.

In the on click event, the context of `this` should be the button itself. Which means using `this`, you can traverse up a parent or two and down into the children to find your text area filled out. You could try also

```
var r_comment = this.closest("form > textarea").val();
```

Theoretically that should traverse to the nearest form in the stack above, then down again to your text area element. Try adding a debugger into your onclick and playing around with the DOM to see where you are and need to be, but that snippet should get you just about there if not what you need.

As an aside, in the future if you are going to mix generated razor markup with JS, it's usually a good idea to assign unique ids with an index using a for loop, that way no matter where you are, you can do a direct ID element lookup based on the control ID you currently have.

Comment: thanks for reply l am new on programming...  l tried to use class against id but result is same  its just working for first comment. other ones text values comes null.. lam trying to do this with closest or parent action but l couldn't make it